# (React) If-else statement in foreach loop in JSX

Tags: reactjs

So I have the following:

```
// Build the component HTML.
return (
  <dl className={ classes }>

    {items.map((item, index) =>
      { item.type === 'dd' ?
        <dd key={ index } index={ index }>{ item.text }</dd>
        :
        <dt className="search-result__description-list__description" key={ index } index={ index }>{ item.text }</dt>
      }
    )}

  </dl>
);
```

The problem: nothing is rendering. The data is present in `items`. When I simply log the content without the if-else statement it also returns my data. However, when I use the if-else statement nothing shows up. No errors ether.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot **return** statement

```
// Build the component HTML.
return (
  <dl className={ classes }>

    {items.map((item, index) =>
      { return item.type === 'dd' ?
        <dd key={ index } index={ index }>{ item.text }</dd>
        :
        <dt className="search-result__description-list__description" key={ index } index={ index }>{ item.text }</dt>
      }
    )}

  </dl>
);
```

You can see this fiddle with the same logic:
https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/94452/

Comment: I need coffee >-< Thx for the prompt answer!

Comment: @WarreBuysse coffee can be really helpful in forgotten return keywords. To be specific: fat arrow function (which are borrowed from CoffeeScript). You can write fiddle from my answer without any return word!
https://jsfiddle.net/yeg9et8w/

Comment: Where did you learn to "speak" React so fluently? I'm working the basics here but I want/need to get more advanced in it. Any books/tutorials you can recommend? Or are you just a plain genious? ;-)

Comment: @WarreBuysse I don't now react (yet). Those topics aren't related with react, those are ES6 concepts. You can read about them in this great book:
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20&%20beyond/README.md#you-dont-know-js-es6--beyond 
Especially this chapter can be helpful for you:
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20&%20beyond/ch2.md#arrow-functions

Comment: @WarreBuysse You can play more with mentioned fiddle even more (remove unnecessary brackets) https://jsfiddle.net/zu38wt6t/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your arrow function, when using the block syntax (`{}s` following the arrow), you will need to specify the returned value using the `return` keyword.